# How to pass a JSON Schema to Angular CLI to generate custom components/forms

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular6-json-schema-form

My team needs to generate various custom forms frequently. To automate the procedure, we are trying to find a way in which we can pass a JSON schema of the form we want to create to Angular CLI, and have it generate the files for the component with the basic stubbed form controls and buttons etc, which we can edit later on.

Can someone point us in the right direction?

Basically, something like

```
ng g c <my-form-component> [usual cli options here] [my json schema for my component]
```

I was reading about angular schematics, but wasn't sure if that is indeed what we need.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: I had to make my own. Unfortunately, the solution is in a company repo. If you are still interested, we can discuss somewhere.